# Show related content. Search results?

Tags: views, panels

I am working on an Equipment Checkout system using Drupal 7, MERCI, views, panels, rules, and many other modules. I am working for a community college in Oregon. I am upgrading features on an already running system that was built by myself with the help of a few other people last year. The system is offline for the summer.

One of the features that I am trying to implement is that when we pull up a customer account, we also see content related to the customer blog posts, reservations, and some custom content types.

I have created a block called 'Customer History' on the customer view for the information to be displayed.

So now I need to figure out how to get the content into that block.

I'm thinking that I could somehow do a search for the customers name and display results in the block. What do you think? Is this a good way to go?

Any help would be great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Views is probably your best option, using a contextual filter, and various Views Blocks

If for example the url was www.mysite.com/user/12/profile, you could list all of any number of content types where the user id matches 12.

The specific answer depends on the structure however. If you include that information, I will update this answer with more specific direction.

**EDIT 1:**

- create a separate view for each content type you want visible on the user's page
- for each, set it as a BLOCK, not a page, and set the fields and order, etc as appropriate
- set a contextual filter - this will depend on your structure, but I will show one as an example and you should be able to extrapolate. Contextual Filter->Content:Author uid
- Contextual Filter, When not Available -> Provide Default Value, Raw Value from URL, Path Component 2 (for /user/12/*)
- go to admin/structure/blocks and you should see the new views blocks. set them to only show on user/* for example to show in the profile pages, and place the blocks in the appropriate region

Comment: Yea! Thank you for your help Geoff :) A few additional pieces of information that might be useful. I am running Drupal on a local host server, If that matters and the customers are custom content types. The URL to our "Damaged Items" customer is `code`localhost:8082/node/2527`code` We use this account to temporarily remove items from inventory when they are getting repaired. Could you please tell me what structure you need from me? Thank you again

Comment: I have been working through your instructions and have a few questions. I created 2 views and set them both as a block. The next instruction was to "set the fields and order, etc" Im not sure what fields to set. I would like to display a list of teasers, similar to a search engine result. The next instruction is to choose a contextual filter and I got lost. I did some looking around on the topic but i am still confused. Can you help me figure out what contextual filter I need to choose?

Comment: Followed all your instructions, and from what I can gather the contextual filter is going to look in the url at position 1 for the author id. I'm assuming at some point I need to tell Drupal to put the author ID into the url at position 1? Also I'm not sure if this is relevant here but, Our checkout is run by an attendant that will be viewing multiple customer accounts in a shift. So the customer never has access to the system. Is Author ID still the best choice?  Thank You again Geoff you are a life saver :)

Comment: I set the contextual filter to Content:L# (This is the customer number) Then in the preview area I typed in an active L# and I get a teaser of the customer content type. So some success! now if we can get it to display reservation content types instead of customer content types. While in the contextual filters, I stumbled across Search: Search Terms. While testing it seemed to return the search results like I am looking for. Have you ever used this filter?

Comment: I set the Filter criteria to Content: type(=Reservation). When I type in an L# in the preview area nothing shows up. Thinking there might not be content to display, I than created a reservation with my L# and tried again, and again nothing came up. Any Ideas? Is there maybe something I need to set in the L# field?

Comment: Does the contextual filter refer to a field that is in the reservation content type or in the customer content type? The field in the reservation content is called field_customer and is formatted (L#xxxxxxxx - Student Name). And in the customer content type the two are separate fields, field_name and field_l_. So the information is not formatted the same. Could this be our problem? Thanks Again man :)

Comment: The Current content type is Customer and the field is field_l_. So i set the contextual filter to field_l_ and the filter to type=reservation. I then type in an L# with associated reservations, and nothing shows up in the preview area. Does the field  need to be in the reservation too?

Comment: ah.. that makes lots of sense. Im going to do some rearranging of my fields so that the field that is in my reservation content type will be in the customer content type also. Ill get back to you on my finding :)

Comment: Once I got the same field in both content types things worked great! Thanks again :) It is exciting when things work. So now can you help me get the field into the URL position 4?

Comment: We will access the Customer Accounts via links from two sources; search, and a direct link from reservations. But mostly from search. I have two views created "Customer Related Reservations", and "Customer Related Forum Posts". Both are displayed in a Mini Panel called "Customer Related Information". The Mini Panel is set to be displayed in the content area, and set only to be displayed on Customer content types.

Comment: for the search, if you implement the search as part of a view, it is quite simple - if you want to use core search, you will need to write a custom module to handle it. The reservation depends on too many variables to get into in this comment

Comment: The search is implemented as part of a view, lets start there.

Comment: The search is set to display as a table. The field l# is already one of the fields displayed, so I did not create a new field, and kept it displayed. Added Global:Custom Text to the fields. Under Rewrite results, I ticked Output this field as a link, in the link path I put [field_l_]. Tested and no luck. I changed the other view to look in the URL 1st position for the L#, and again no luck. I noticed that the url that is displayed when the Customer Page is loaded does not have the information in it, it looks like the url before I inserted the Global Text.

Comment: The Global Text does not appear in the table, is it supposed to give me a link to click on that appears in the search results? After searching for a customer the url looks like this localhost:8082/search-customers?field_l__value=00229635 I then click on the title of the customer page and it loads the customer content type, localhost:8082/node/3598

Comment: Had some-kind of brain malfunction yesterday, I was editing one view and testing a different view. Now that I am back on track, The URL I get when I click on the global text link is localhost:8082/00229635 The URL to the actual customer account is localhost:8082/node/3598 It looks like I need to change the link path somehow? This makes me think I should be saving my customer accounts to be the L# instead of the nid. If this would help I can implement it.

Comment: OK, Im good at tinkering, it's gotten me this far lol :) It looks like there is a prefix field, that I set to /node/ then my url should be /node/[field_l_], then I rename my customer accounts to be the same as [field_l_]. I think I saw an auto rename node feature. Thank you for helping me get thro a lot of this, I can already see ways to use this in other places on my site. I'll ping here again if I have further questions. Thanks Again!

Comment: Thats a good idea! once I get the link correct, I should end up with localhost8082:node/[nid]/[field_l_], and tell my view to look in the 3rd spot for the information?

Comment: OMG it worked!!! You Rock Geoff! Thank you for sticking around, your a rock star! :)

Comment: no problem - I will update the answer with everything we talked about tonight or tomorrow, and you should accept this answer so the question doesn't appear unanswered going forward